# String comparison fails when comparing with a data from file

Tags: c++, string, loops, file, struct

I am trying to calculate how many males and females from data obtained from a file. But when i placed

```
struct pneumonia
{
string gender;
}patientInfo[3];

//inside main func

ifstream p("patient.txt");
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    getline(p,patientInfo[i].gender,';');
}

int tm=0, tf=0;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    if (patientInfo[i].gender == "female")
        tf++;
    else
        tm++;
}
cout<<"Male :"<<tm<<"\nFemale :"<<tf<<endl;
```

the data in the file contains 2 females and 1 male but when i run the program it outputs 2 males and 1 female.
The data from the file is as below

*female; Mariam Binti Ramli; 2 7*

*female; Aisyah Binti Salleh; 4 3*

*male; Nuh Harraz Bin Amirul; 3 5*

Anyone knows what the problem is?

full coding below for anyone interested

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

struct pneumonia
{
    string name;
    string gender;
    int age;
    int ward;
}patientInfo[3];

int main()
{
    ifstream p("patient.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    getline(p,patientInfo[i].gender,';');
    getline(p,patientInfo[i].name,';');
    p>>patientInfo[i].age>>patientInfo[i].ward;
    cout<<patientInfo[i].gender<<" "<<patientInfo[i].name<<" "<<patientInfo[i].age<<" "<<patientInfo[i].ward<<endl;
}
p.close();
int tm=0, tf=0,l=0;
string ln;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    if (patientInfo[i].gender == "female")
        tf++;
    else
        tm++;
        
    if (patientInfo[i].ward>l)
    {
        l=patientInfo[i].ward;
        ln=patientInfo[i].name;
    }
}
cout<<"Male :"<<tm<<"\nFemale :"<<tf<<endl;
cout<<"Longest stay :"<<ln<<"\nDays : "<<l;
```

}

Comment: please post the complete code ([mcve]). In the code you did post there is no output

Comment: Run your program under a debugger and see what you get back on the second invocation of `getline`. Alternatively, check what `patientInfo[1].gender` contains.

Comment: whoops sorry abt that, it had been added in

Comment: Please also include the includes. A mcve is something others can copy and paste to compile and see the same you do. Hardcoding the input also helps. It took me more time to add the includes and usings and input than to find the bug: https://godbolt.org/z/hTxdfc4Y9. Posting a [mcve] makes it much easier for others to help you

Comment: `<string.h>` is the wrong header. `std::string` is from `<string>`. The code may still compile because headers are free to include other headers but you should not rely on that

Answer (score 1):

When you use `getline` on that input and three times with the `;` delimiter you end up with

```
patientInfo[] = {
    "female",
    " Mariam Binti Ramli",
    " 2 7"
};
```

Not what you're expecting. Your comparison with "female" is true only once.

What you could do instead is:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    string line;
    getline(p, line, '\n');
    stringstream ss(line)
    getline(ss, patientInfo[i].gender, ';');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so ive managed to get the answer i wanted but i don't understand how it works, i put

```
p.ignore()
```

after

```
    getline(p,patientInfo[i].gender,';');
    getline(p,patientInfo[i].name,';');
    p>>patientInfo[i].age>>patientInfo[i].ward;
    p.ignore();
```